# Print variable from class to php-page

Tags: php

I don't know how I can return a variable from a class, to another php-page.

**Here I fill the class and put it into a session:**

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM gebruiker";

$result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die("Er is een fout opgetreden bij het uitvoeren van de query: \"$query\"");

while($rij = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    if ($rij['ID'] == $_SESSION['user'])
    {
        $naam = $rij['Naam'];

        include_once("class/Gebruikers.php");
        include_once("class/Admin.php");

        //class invullen
        $admin1 = new Admin($rij['ID'], $rij['Naam'], $rij['E-mail'], $rij['Rechten']);
        $_SESSION['admin'] = $admin1;

    }       
}
```

**This is my class file:**

```
class Admin extends Gebruiker
{
    private $m_rechten;

    public function printen($recht)
    {
         $rechten = $this->m_rechten
         return $rechten;
    }

    public function __toString() 
    {

        return $this->m_rechten;
    }

    public function __construct($p_ID="", $p_naam="",$p_email="",$p_rechten="")
    {
        parent::__construct($p_ID, $p_naam,$p_email);

            $this->m_rechten=$p_rechten;
    }
}
?>
```

**Here's my other page where I want to print the result from the class.**

```
    session_start();

    //check to make sure the session variable is registered

    $result = $_SESSION['admin']->printen($recht);

    print $result;
?>
```

My error is

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'return' (T_RETURN) in C:\Users\vincent\Documents\XAMPP\htdocs\PHP\Project\class\Admin.php on line 12

Comment: So, which is the problem?

Comment: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'return' (T_RETURN) in C:\Users\vincent\Documents\XAMPP\htdocs\PHP\Project\class\Admin.php on line 12" This is the error i'm having...

Comment: Add the error to the question, not here in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

Here you need to add `;`:

```
public function printen($recht)
{
     $this->m_rechten = $recht; // <-- HERE the ; | Use the $recth variable, not $recthen
     return $this->m_rechten;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but now I'm getting this error: "Notice: Undefined variable: recht in C:\Users\vincent\Documents\XAMPP\htdocs\PHP\Project\Administrator.php on line 21". I don't know why it's giving this error...